# SQLXMLBULKLOAD XSD check for element value before load

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, bulk-load

I am using SQLXMLBULKLOAD library to load a xml file using a xsd. Below is the section from XSD.

```
<xsd:element name="Information" sql:is-constant="1">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>                                                              
      <xsd:element name="E_Code" type="xsd:string" sql:is-constant="1"/>                                                                
      <xsd:element name="E_Amount" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" sql:field="Amount_Paid"/>
      <xsd:element name="E_Quantity" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" sql:is-constant="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>.
```

The Element "Information" shown above can occur 10 times and i need to check if 'E_Code' = "xxxx" then only consider information block & E-Amount to bulk load otherwise proceed to the next information block for same condition check. Is it possible to do this in the schema file?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

XSD is a language for defining validity conditions on XML documents; it's not designed as a way to control the behavior of database loaders, and it would be surprising if you could control the behavior of a loader by changes to the XSD schema.

Comment: Thanks Sperberg. But what is the Best way to allow Bulk loader to load a specfic xml block based on some conditions? Thanks in advance

Comment: If the loader can be configured in the way you describe, I'd expect to see something useful in the loader documentation.  From your description, what you're looking for is a way to control the loader, not a way to define validity of your input.  So look to the loader, not to the schema, for your mechanism.